# How to find the two most frequently occurring domains from a list of email addresses?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to programming, and what I want to do is the following:

For example I have:

```
a@hotmail.com
b@hotmail.com
c@hotmail.com
g@gmail.com
s@gmail.com
h@msn.com
h@yahoo.com
```

I need to find the two most frequently used email domains. In the example, that's `hotmail.com` and `gmail.com`.

How do I go about doing that with a shell script?

Comment: The question is unclear.  Are you trying to count the number of unique  domain names here?  i.e. you have hotmail, gmail, msn and yahoo, so a total of 4?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Generally speaking, people here won't write your code for you, but will help you fix an honest attempt at solving the problem.  Learning to program requires you to think logically about the steps you need to go through, and then find a mechanism to achieve those steps.  For example, you're going to need to modify the contents of the file (without modifying the file itself) so that you have just the domain names.  Then you're going to need to count the occurrences of each domain, then find the two most frequent domains.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh, I dunno, people will try to answer all kinds of questions. But the quality of the answer depends greatly on the quality of the question.

Comment: Ignore my comment. I thought the comments were aimed a question I asked, and that you guys had edited it. God I am an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `uniq -c` to count the number of each item in a sorted list of items. Armed with this, we just cut and sort appropriately:

```
$ cut -d @ -f 2 yourlist | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn

  3 hotmail.com
  2 gmail.com
  1 yahoo.com
  1 msn.com

$
```

Comment: I think your first sort is unnecessary.  Also if all that is required is *just* the domain names, then you could `head` and `cut` it a bit: `cut -d @ -f 2 yourlist | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n2 | cut -c9-`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma The first sort is necessary if the itmes are not in order. You need a sorted list for `uniq` to work because `uniq` only checks adjacent lines. If the list does't have all the domain names together, it would work. Not sure why you have head and the second cut.

Comment: @DavidW. - Point taken about the `sort` before `uniq` - it *is* necessary.  The question asks for the "two most frequently occurring domains".  So we can used head -n2 to give the top 2 from the top of the list.  The cut -c9- simply strips the sort index off the beginning of this line.  Presumably only the names of the domains are required, and not any counts.

Comment: Okay. I see about the head and cut. However, I would do it with `awk` since you can do that with a single command `awk NR <= 2 {print $2}`. You could also use `sed` too, but the syntax is more complex `sed -n '1,2s/^.* //p'`

Answer (score 1):

This could get you started. It counts the occurrences of each domain and then sorts them descending by count.

```
awk -F'@' 'domains[$2]++{} END{ for (d in domains) print d, domains[d]; }' | sort -rnk2
```